# Convert List Elements with Text, Inline and Paragraph Elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I try to convert my List Element from html to xml. 
The problem is that the List Element contains paragraphs elements and sometimes the first note is Text.
I will copy the paragraphs with apply-templates command and nest the first text note into a p tag.
So the Problem is, that the first text node also may contain an inline tags like a, span or img. 
So, I think I need something like this. 
If the first note, is a text note, then copy everything until the next p Tag into a separate p tag.

This is my source code

```
    <li> Text1<span>Text</span>Test<img src=".."><a>text</a> 
<p>Text2</p> 
</li>
```

This is how it should look like

```
    <li> 
<p>Text1<span>Text</span>Test<img src=".."><a>text</a></p> 
<p>Text2</p> 
</li>
```

Ate the moment my xlst ist this

```
<xsl:template match="li/text()">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p> 
</xsl:template>
```

The result of this xlst is wrong

```
<li>
<p>Text1</p>
<span>Text</span>
<p>Test</p>
<img src=".."><a>text</a>
 <p>Text2</p> 
</li>
```

Is there a possibility to do this?

Comment: And what would happen with an input `<li><span>Text>test<img src=".."/><p>p2</p></li>`, do you also want to wrap that content into a `p` element? Please also state whether you can use XSLT 2.0 or are restricted to XSLT 1.0.

Comment: "*So the Problem is, that the first text node also may contain an inline tags like a, span or img*" .No, that is an incorrect description. A text node cannot contain other nodes. What you have is several nodes (text and elements) that come before the first `p`.

Comment: Yes, both of you right

Answer (score 0):

> So, I think I need something like this. If the first note, is a text note, then copy everything until the next p Tag into a separate p tag

Try something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="li">
    <xsl:variable name ="pn" select="p[1]/preceding-sibling::node()" />
    <xsl:if test="$pn" >
        <p>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pn"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:copy-of  select="p[1]"/>
    <xsl:copy-of  select="p[1]/following-sibling::node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The above template copies every thing before the first `p` element into an new `p` element and copies the remaining nodes (first `p`and everything following).